# Represent assigning part of a vector in a schematic | VHDL

Tags: digital-logic, vhdl, schematics, schematic

In my VHDL I have

```
signal m1, m2 : unsigned(7 downto 0);
signal result : unsigned(31 downto 0);
```

I am using an 8-bit multiplier for `m1 * m2` which results in a 16-bit value. Then I am placing this value into only part of `result` shown below:

```
result <= (others => '0');
if (a) then
    result(23 downto 8) <= m1 * m2;
else if (b) then
    result(31 downto 16) <= m1 * m2;
end if;
```

I'm not sure how to represent this in a schematic. What kind of hardware will go in the place where I marked purple. I know there will be a mux but not sure about assigning part of a vector:
[image]

Comment: Not answerable without seeing the complete code. Especially the architecture.

Comment: @MituRaj it's hundreds of lines. Could you assume ideally or more often than not what kind of hardware will be generated?

Comment: We don't know if this is combinatorial or synchronous

Comment: Which values do the other bits of `result` receive that are not assigned?

Comment: @thebusybee in the code I set `result <= (others => '0');` before doing the multiplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need two stages of multiplexers, because you have three possible choices:

1. `a` is true (`b` is irrelevant),
2. `a` is false and `b` is true,
3. `a` and `b` are false.

This is a possible solution:

[image: Schematic]